# C++ code is getting a segmentation fault and I have no clue as to why

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, computer-science, unsigned-integer

Something seems to be very wrong with my code (below) and I cannot figure out what it may be. I have spent hours on it and cannot figure it out. I keep getting a segfault and, according to visual studio, it is happening in my InitializeMatrix function. I am trying to use optimize storage by using unsigned integers, and I thought this may be the root of my problems, but I changed each unsigned integer into an int in the InitializeMatrix function to no avail. If anyone could spot something I may be over-looking, or explain what I am doing incorrectly, I would be very grateful. Thank you in advance for the assistance.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the data entered? Is `dimension` always less or equal to `MAX`?

Comment: Do you have a number of row throwing the segfault?

Comment: Try reading from `cin` instead of `inFile` - that will fix the data-related issues (like, file does not exist etc)

Comment: Where *exactly* do you get segfault? Have you tried to *debug* your code? If you've figured this, please show us the lines where it causes segfault.

Comment: This code cannot give a segfault. It doesn't compile. `dimension` in `PartialPivot` is undefined.

Comment: "I am trying to use optimize storage by using unsigned integers". If that's what your school teaches you, you should demand your money back.

Comment: See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: Incidentally, `i <= dimension` looks suspicious.  If `dimension` is 2, I would expect you to write to `column1row[0]`, and `column1row[1]`, but actually you write to `column1row[2]` too.  You almost always want `<` in a for loop.

Comment: Please learn to use a debugger. This will be your best friend in case of segmentation fault.

Comment: Can you try printing some message before every line until you figure out the line that throws the segfault? And don't forget to add a line break because when there's a segfault the prints might not flush and using a line break will force flush. After that we may be able to help you.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 Changing to cin actually made it work just fine, which tells me it must be something in my data file.

Comment: @n.m. dimension was defined in main and passed into PartialPivot by reference.

Comment: @MartinBonner Thank you for the recommendation. And yes, I know one would typically use i < dimension but, right after I read in the value for the dimension, I decremented the value. I did this for readability as I am writing the program for a mathematics course.

Comment: For some reason, after running the code using cin then switching back to reading from inFIle, my code works flawlessly. This is both nice and very unsettling.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like dimension is greater than MAX.
Possible solution is to change Ai1 and A arrays to pointers. 
And after entering into InitializeMatrix() you can use "new" or "malloc" with "dimension" size to allocate those pointers